# CSS various color, background color, border color values and speed

Tags: css, performance, woocommerce, colors, wordpress-theming

I am customizing a wordpress-woocommerce theme via the child's theme "style.css" file and I am noticing with chrome inspect that many areas with text have various shades of black color:

```
.example1 {color: #111111;}

.example2 {color: #222222;}

.example3 {color: #323232;}
```

A) Now, I only use `#000000` for text. While I know we are talking milliseconds here, but when it comes to performance/speed and rendering though, technically speaking, would it be better for me to change all text to:

```
.example1, .example2, .example3 {color: #000000;}
```

Or would the extra added lines increase time in ms?

B) In a similar fashion, there are other areas (like buttons, swatches etc.) with background-color and border-color that have different shades of grey:

```
.example4 {background-color: #f8f8f8;}

.example5 {background-color: #eeeeee;}

.example6 {background-color: #cccccc;}

.example7 {border-color: #808080;}

.example8 {border-color: #e2e2e2;}

.example9 {border-color: #dbdbdb;}
```

Would it be better for me keep the same logic and use as few colors as I can, merge them all into one color or leave the default settings? Ideally, I would like to combine a maximum of 3 different colours here (in order to also have a visually appealing site).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If a color is being set on an element I can't see that having the same color as is being set on another element would make any difference to speed - it still needs to be set.

Comment: @AHaworth Perhaps I didn't use the rights words, excuse my english.
For question A, if I overwrite the 3 examples with #000000, then the other 3 colors are not displayed, correct? But now I added more lines in css, correct?
So, if that's the case, which is faster, leave it as it is or merge 3 colors to one (#000000)?
Something similar for question B...